# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

My code is given below the error I am facing issue in accessing the username from firebase in this line

`snapshot.data['username']`

It gives the error mentioned above

The only way I know to access the map data is this

```dart
FutureBuilder<Object>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users')
   .doc(userId)
   .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading...");
    }
    return Text(
      snapshot.data['username'],
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: did you solve this, i am also having this problem now

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the new flutter update, we don't need to add `.data()`

I got this error and after removing `.data()` it was solved.

```
FutureBuilder<Object>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users')
   .doc(userId)
   .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading...");
    }
    return Text(
      snapshot['username'],
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer which will help others to understand your approach easily.

Comment: @PawaraSiriwardhane I guess what Shamil was saying is, snapshot.data()['username'] can be replaced with snapshot['username'].

Comment: @ZubliQuzaini the answer did not consist of any context other than the code. That is why asked to provide some description along with the code. Later he has edited the answer and added some descriptions.

Comment: Ahh I see, my bad then @PawaraSiriwardhane

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me!

Try switching

```
snapshot.data['username']
```

with

```
(snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)['username']
```

Answer (score 5):

In the newer versions of Flutter you have to specify the type for FutureBuilder as DocumentSnapshot. Edit your code like below:

```
           FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc(userId)
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) 
                {
                  return const Text('Loading...');
                }
                return Text(
                  snapshot.data!['username'],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                );
              }),
```

This should work for you.

Comment: This was the right solution for (as of now) latest flutter and firebase versions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this format for the updated version of Flutter.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userId)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text("Loading..");
                    }
                    return Text(
                      snapshot.requireData['username'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    );
                  }),
```

This solution is for the **lecture number 336** at **4:30mins** of the Udemy Course of Flutter **A Complete Guide to the Flutter SDK & Flutter Framework for building native iOS and Android apps** .
*Created by, Academind by Maximilian Schwarzmuller*

Answer (score 1):

`snapshot.data` is the data returned by `FutureBuilder`. So technically `snapshot.data` is a type of `DocumentSnapshot`. To access this document's data, you should use `snapshot.data.data()` or this code below:

```dart
FutureBuilder<Object>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users')
   .doc(userId)
   .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data;
      return Text(
        doc.data()['username'],
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      );
    }
    return Text("Loading...");
  }
),
```

Answer (score 1):

To the updated version, you have to specify the type for **FutureBuilder as DocumentSnapshot**. Also the **data** is changed to **requiredData**.
Edit your code like below:

```
       FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(userId)
              .get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) 
            {
              return const Text('Loading...');
            }
            return Text(
              snapshot.requiredData['username'],
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            );
          }),
```

And now your code will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

do that : add  ( AsyncSnapshot) as that

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (ConnectionState.waiting == snapshot.connectionState) {
                  return const Text('...chargement');
                }

                return Text(snapshot.data['name']);
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  snapshot.data['username'],
```

into this:

```
  snapshot.data.data()['username'];
```

`data()` is a method

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'

Comment: `FutureBuilder<Object>` remove the type here

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy to do and it worked for me.

```
  FutureBuilder<Object>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users')
   .doc(userId)
   .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   var data=snapshot.data as Map;
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading...");
    }
    return Text(
      data['username'],
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
(snapshot as AsyncSnapshot).data["username"]
```

Answer (score -2):

(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>) ['your field'];
//This actually worked for me try it...