# Firebase Firestore Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im learning how to connect flutter app to firebase from this video

> https://youtu.be/ggYTQn4WVuw

For me everything is exactly the same, but in Android Studio there is an error.

> error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [firebase_test] lib\services\database.dart:24)

Code where is error:

```
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return Brew(
    name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
    strength: doc.data()['strength'] ?? 0,
    sugars: doc.data()['sugars'] ?? '0',
  );
}).toList();}
```

Brew Class:

```
class Brew {
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  Brew({ this.name, this.sugars, this.strength });
}
```

Can someone help me fix this? Is this a problem with Android Studio?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67610936/7015400

Answer (score 13):

You are using the latest Firestore dependency, version 2.0.0, which was released May 4th, 2021 days ago. There are breaking changes, read about them [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog).

"Add withConverter", From the documentation:

> Add withConverter function to CollectionReference, DocumentReference and Query (#6015). This new method allows interacting with collections/documents in a type-safe way:

```
final modelsRef = FirebaseFirestore
     .instance
     .collection('models')
     .withConverter<Model>(
       fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
       toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
     );

 Future<void> main() async {
   // Writes now take a Model as parameter instead of a Map
   await modelsRef.add(Model());
   final Model model = await modelsRef.doc('123').get().then((s) => s.data());
 }
```

Or, you can use simply:

```
String name = snapshot.data.get('name');
//instead of 
String name = (snapshot.data.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)['name']
```

And if you want the entire map:

```
Map<String,dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data() as Map<String,dynamic>);
String name = data['name'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Hi! Having the same problem after upgrading dependencies. I do not understand how to read that changelog you linked to!... What does the number in "FIX: withConverter examples in docs (#6438)" mean? As in, what does the #6438 stand for? Is there any place I can get a more elaborate explanation...?

Comment: I edited my answer @karolina, check now if it works

Comment: I already realized that I could put the entire document in a `Map<String, dynamic>` coz I noticed I had already done that in other places in my code, and those bits hadn't crashed!... But my question was specifically about the change logs! And if I can get more elaborate info, not from StackOverflow? I found some official info, but it doesn't seem to be accurate... Wait, I'll show you.

Comment: Here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-methods it seems to say that `.get()` will return `null` if the field doesn't exist. It also says that I can test whether it exists using `.contains()`. But when I try it, `contains()` doesn't exist, and `.get()` doesn't return `null`, it crashes the app!!...  Where do I find ACCURATE information about this version of the package??

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
doc.get('name') ?? '',
```

Instead of:

```
doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
```

Comment: This will not work if 'name' does not exist. It will not fall back to '', because of StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)

Answer (score 1):

**First solution:**

Your Brew Class:

```
class Brew {
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  Brew({ this.name, this.sugars, this.strength });
  
  Brew.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
          name: json['name'] as String,
          sugars: json['sugars'] as String,
          strength: json['strength'] as int,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'sugars': sugars,
      'strength': strength,
    };
  }
}
```

Your service:

```
List<Brew> _brewListCollectionReference (CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference) {
  QuerySnapshot<Object?> snapshot = await collectionReference.withConverter<Brew>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshots, _ ) => Recipe.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
          toFirestore: (brew, _ ) => brew.toJson(),
        ).get();
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Brew).toList();
}
```

*Note: Your **"collectionReference"** is the reference from your firebase collection.*

*For example:* `firestore.collection('brewCollection')`

**Second solution:**

```
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return Brew(
    name: doc['name'] ?? '',
    strength: doc['strength'] ?? 0,
    sugars: doc['sugars'] ?? '0',
  );
}).toList();}
```

**Third solution:**

```
List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return Brew(
    name: doc.get('name') ?? '',
    strength: doc.get('strength') ?? 0,
    sugars: doc.get('sugars') ?? '0',
  );
}).toList();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Flutter now doesn't need the `.data()` to work properly. So change your code to represent `doc['name']`.

Source: [The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086647/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-try-defining-the-operator)