# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' since update of Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

After few months off, I am working again on my project. I have updated Flutter version and now I can't run my application any more.
I am getting a lot of errors.

I have done some google search, but I have not find a clear solution. Your help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

```
child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  
                        children:
                        snapshot.data.docs.map((documentSnapshot) {
                        print(documentSnapshot.data());

                        recordID = documentSnapshot.id; 
                          return Text(documentSnapshot
                              .data()['task_Name']); //Error is The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
                        }
                        ).toList(),
                      ),
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447001/firebase-firestore-error-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object)  answer your question? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob/67610936#67610936)

Comment: I prefer not to use Json. I would like to use only FireBase. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of data you're expecting from your `DocumentSnapshot` from `cloud_firestore` `2.0.0`.

Check out the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/#migration).

You should update your code to this:

```dart
    Map<String, dynamic> snapshotData = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Text(snapshotData['task_Name']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your solution, but I am getting a new error message
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: Check the console, what line is the error pointing to?

Comment: line 74 which is the line of 
return Text(documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>['task_Name']);

Comment: Alright. I've updated the code. Please try this one.

Comment: on this view, it seems to work. I do not see anymore the error message.
But, I have tried in another place and I have not been able to make it works. Please, would you be OK to help me again?
```

```
 child: Text(
                              document.data()['contexts'],
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),

Comment: You can do the same thing:
`Text(snapshotData['contexts']);`

Comment: Many thanks. I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

By observing your data and the code I think documentsnapshot.data() contains object not the json data.\

whenever you are calling  documentSnapshot.data()["task_Name"] it is throwing error

This was the problem i found with the code you provided

please confirm what your documentsnapshot.data() consists of by printing it.

Comment: I am using FireBase. I hope this help. In fact, right now, I can't run the application. Since the update of flutter, I am getting this error in all my views.

Comment: can i know what u got when u print the documentsnapshot.data() like atleast  add some info in commnets

Comment: Before updating, it was working perfectly. I guess that with the update, there is a new way to write the code