# Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1) Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

**Scheme not starting with alphabetic character **

**this is my code if you can please help me cuz i dont know what to do. I was watching a tutorial on Youtube on how to create an ecommerce app and I got this error while trying to retrieve the images from firebase. I tried to get rid of the if null operator ?? but i got another error that says (The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null').:**

```
import 'package:email_password_login/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productsRef =FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ///////////
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _productsRef.get(),
            builder: (context,snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasError){
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child:Text("Error:${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),

                );

              }


              //collection data ready to display
              if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
                //display data inside a list view
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
                    return Container(
                      child: Image.network(
                          "${document.data()?? ["images"][0]} "
                      ),
                    );

                  }).toList(),
                );

              }

              //loading state
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child:CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),

              );

            },
          ),
          /////////
          CustomActionBar(
            hasTitle: true,
            title:'Home',
            hasBackArrow: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this picture is the error that i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP5sV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing a map (`doc.data()`) to `Image.network` but it expects a `String`. Get rid of your if null operator `??`:

```
Image.network("${document.data()["images"][0]}"),
```

Comment: I tried that before and when i did i got an error that says  :The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. @hnnngwdlch

Comment: Change it to `document.data()!["images"][0]`. If not all of your documents have an image field, you might consider providing a fallback image.

Comment: hey man i did that just now and i got ((The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.)) @hnnngwdlch

Comment: Please try `(document.data()!["image"] as Iterable<String>).first`

Comment: just did that and i got the same error again ((The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.)) @hnnngwdlch

Comment: any other solutions @hnnngwdlch ? and btw thank u

Comment: It should be `snapshot.docs.map` and not `snapshot.data!.docs.map`. Just saw that... What's written to the console if you print `document.data()`?

Comment: Sorry `snapshot.data!.docs.map` should be correct since you use a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: yup yup . i was just going to tell u that i got an error

Comment: so do you have any idea how can i fix that ? Believe it or not it been 3 days without sleeping  properly trying to find  a solution .

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the first image string with `document.data()["images"].first` or `document.data()["images"][0]`. Works for me in my collection at least. Could you share what is printed to the console for `document.data()`?

Comment: with this code i cant print anything ` "${document.data()["images"][0]} " ` but with this  "${document.data()??["images"][0]} "  im getting ======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following FormatException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1) @hnnngwdlch

Comment: which is the error i mentioned above in my question and i attached a photo with it in case u didnt see it

Comment: Yes, I meant you could print your docs prior to returning your `ListView` for example: `for (var doc in snapshot.data!.docs) {
      print(doc.data());
    }` to check your documents data. I would expect that at least one of your docs in the Products collection does not have an `images` field. For such cases you could provided a fallback image. Example: `doc.data()["images"] != null ? doc.data()["images"][0] : "YOUR FALLBACK URL"`.

Comment: actually i deleted the collection previously and i added just one image to check if its working but it didnt work .and no my docs in the products collection does have an image and it has only one image so what could be the problem than ?

Comment: and when i print this is what i got I/flutter (19990): {images: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/login-9449c.appspot.com/o/pink%20flowers.png?alt=media&token=e8f37312-9344-4f94-9a9f-fe345b8ddc28], size: [5, 10], price: 50, name: Red flower, desc:  HELOOOOO TEST TEST TEST} as i said the image is there . @hnnngwdlch

Comment: Seems there was a breaking change some time ago: Try `doc.get('images')[0]` instead of `doc.data()["images"][0}`. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447001/firebase-firestore-error-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object

Comment: i tried doc.get('images')[0] and i got ((HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/login-9449c.appspot.com/o/pink%20flowers.png?alt=media&token=e8f37312-9344-4f94 9a9f-fe345b8ddc28%20))  @hnnngwdlch