# Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'. - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../db/category.dart';
import '../db/brand.dart';
import 'admin.dart';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

class AddProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddProduct({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddProduct> createState() => _AddProductState();
}

class _AddProductState extends State<AddProduct> {
  final CategoryService _categoryService = CategoryService();
  final BrandService _brandService = BrandService();

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController productNameController = TextEditingController();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> brands = <DocumentSnapshot>[];
  List<DocumentSnapshot> categories = <DocumentSnapshot>[];
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? categoriesDropDown =
      <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> brandsDropDown = <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];
  late String _currentCategory = "";
  late String _currentBrand ="";

  Color white = Colors.white;
  Color black = Colors.black;
  Color grey = Colors.grey;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.3,
        backgroundColor: white,
        leading: IconButton(
          color: black,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Admin()));
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Ürün ekle",
          style: TextStyle(color: black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 40, 14, 40),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 40, 14, 40),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 40, 14, 40),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                "Ürün ismi 5 karakterden uzun olmalıdır!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: productNameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Ürün İsmi",
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Ürün ismi girmelisin";
                  } else if (value.length > 5) {
                    return "Ürün ismi 5 harften uzun olmalıdır";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
           //selected category

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TypeAheadField(
                textFieldConfiguration: const TextFieldConfiguration(
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Kategori ekle" )),
                suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                  return await _categoryService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                  return  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.category),
                   title: Text(suggestion['category']),
                  );
                },
                onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                 _currentCategory=suggestion["category"];
                },
              ),
            ),
            //selected brand

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TypeAheadField(
                textFieldConfiguration: const TextFieldConfiguration(
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Marka ekle")),
                suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                  return await _brandService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.category),
                    title: Text(suggestion["brand"]),

                  );
                },
                onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentBrand = "$suggestion";
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getCategories();
    //_getBrands();
    getCategoriesDropdown();

    //  _currentCategory = categoriesDropDown![0].value!;
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> ?getCategoriesDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        categoriesDropDown?.insert(
            0,
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(categories[i]["category"]),
              value: categories[i]["category"],
            ));
      });
    }
    return items;
  }

  void _getCategories() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> data = await _categoryService.getCategories();
    setState(() {
      categories = data;

    });
  }

}
```

Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
lib/screens/add_product.dart:150:42: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  title: Text(suggestion['category']),
  ^
  lib/screens/add_product.dart:154:45: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  _currentCategory=suggestion["category"];
  ^
  lib/screens/add_product.dart:172:43: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  title: Text(suggestion["brand"]),
  ^

edit__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class CategoryService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String ref = "categories";

  void createCategory(String name) {
    var id = const Uuid();
    String categoryId = id.v1();

    _firestore.collection(ref).doc(categoryId).set({"category": name});
  }

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getCategories() {
    return _firestore.collection(ref).get().then((snaps) {
      return snaps.docs;
    });
  }

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getSuggestions(String suggestion) =>
      _firestore.collection(ref).where("category", isEqualTo: suggestion).get().then((snap){
        return snap.docs;
      });
}


import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class BrandService{
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String ref= "brands";

  void createBrand(String name){
    var id = const Uuid();
    String brandId = id.v1();

    _firestore.collection(ref).doc(brandId).set({"brand": name});
  }

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getBrands()=>
  _firestore.collection(ref).get().then((snaps){
     return snaps.docs;
   });

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getSuggestions(String suggestion) =>
      _firestore.collection(ref).where("brand", isEqualTo: suggestion).get().then((snap) {
        return snap.docs;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `categories` variable is a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`. A `DocumentSnapshot` is a generic type, and if you don't specify what data it contains that data will be of type `Object`. And you can't call `[]` on an object, which is why you get the error message when you do this:

```
categories[i]["category"]
```

The solution is to either pass a type to the `DocumentSnapshot`, or to use the `get()` method, or to cast the data to a `Map`.

Using the `get` method:

```
categories[i].get("category")
```

Casting to a map:

```
(categories[i].data() as Map<String,dynamic>)["category"]
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Firestore Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447001/firebase-firestore-error-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object)
- The reference documentation for [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)