# How to fill Map from DocumentSnapshot in Using Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fill up a **Map** from **DocumentSnapshot** in a Flutter.

but I'm having a syntax error within the code.
This is the code I'm trying to work with:

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> particularItem(String productId) async {
      DocumentSnapshot prodRef = await _productReference.doc(productId).get();
      Map<String, dynamic> itemDetail = new Map();
      itemDetail['image'] = await getProductsImage(prodRef.data()['imageId'][0]);
      itemDetail['color'] = prodRef.data()['color'];
      itemDetail['size'] = prodRef.data()['size'];
      itemDetail['price'] = prodRef.data()['price'];
      itemDetail['name'] = prodRef.data()['name'];
      itemDetail['productId'] = productId;
      return itemDetail;
    }
```

And this is the error I'm getting in the below snippet:

`The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.`

```
prodRef.data()['imageId']
prodRef.data()['color']
prodRef.data()['size']
prodRef.data()['price']
prodRef.data()['name']
```

Comment: Have you checked this StackOverflow threads: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67763957/18265570) & [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873065/18265570)?

Answer (score 0):

You should cast prodRef.data() before use it. In dart object can't not use the operator []

```
final data = prodRef.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Then you can get property from data variable.
For more, you can read here [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)