# Get distance from center with geoflutterfire2 in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the [geoflutterfire2](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2) package to retrieve data within a certain radius.
The documentation mention that for each document you can even get the distance from center.

This is a code snippet that I got from Jeff Delaney tutorial on GeoFlutter.

```
documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
    double distance = document.data['distance'];
```

But I as have learned, I could get the same result just by doing

```
documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    GeoPoint pos = document['position']['geopoint'];
    double distance = document['distance'];
```

So far so gut. Unfortunately I get `error with distance: Bad state: field "distance" does not exist`.

Am using geoflutterfire2 wrong?

Comment: `data` is a function, so needs to be used as `data()`. Alternatively, you can use `document.get('fieldname')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447001/firebase-firestore-error-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object and many other questions about this error message.

Comment: `document['position']['geopoint']` is indeed working. but when I do `document['distance']` or `document.get('distance')` I get `error with distance: Bad state: field "distance" does not exist`