# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object' after migrating to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, dart-null-safety

I migrated my code to null safety but now I get an issue:
When I want to fetch a document from firestore I get this error:

```
Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
```

Here is the code snippet where I want to call ['plans'] on the snapshot data.

```
body: FutureBuilder(
            future: handler.getPlans(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final plans = snapshot.data!['plans']; /// here I cant call ['plans']
```

Before null safety this worked. Whats the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The operator '\[\]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '\[\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086647/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-try-defining-the-operator)

Comment: No without the '!' i get this error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: I think its not about the '!'. The answers are about the type of the FutureBuilder (FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>)

Comment: Thank you this was the issue! I also needed to add a '?'

Comment: You are welcome. Where exactly do u want to add the '?'? At the type?

Comment: I needed to add 'FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>.' I think because my future handler.getPlans() can catch an error